# Some VS tabs keep unsticking when selected

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Here is the normal environment. My documents' tabs are normal.

[image]

Now I click on the other tab to select it and it pops out like this.

[image]

What confuses me even more is that it happens only with .rpt files. All the other file types are working normally (simply select the tab).

I haven't found any option nor help on this topic.

Thank you!

Comment: Does the problem also happen if you cycle through the tabs using CTRL+TAB and CTRL+SHIFT+TAB?  If not you could at least use that as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks, it is a working workaround. Not perfect, but it's a progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click and drag a file it pops out like that. If it's doing it without the dragging, that's probably a VS bug.

Comment: As nobody has an answe to this, I think you must be right and it must be a bug. That's unfortunate. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vscrystalreports/thread/fb6d3588-1481-46a2-8284-90dbb40c42f6

Comment: How does this help with regard to tabs?

Comment: it seems OP is not able to see the .rpt files and instead getting junk chars. So the solution accordingly.

Comment: 'Junk chars' is NOT the problem: it's that one tab takes over the tab-bar, and the others disappear.

Comment: The file works well so this is not the problem. Thank you for you time though